# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client even after return statement is added (React)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, routes

I am getting a ' Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client' error for the /api/users/profile route and have been trying to fix it. I chanced upon some answers on stackoverflow suggesting to add a return statement - tried adding it in my userController.js file but still didn't work. Appreciate any help to fix this, thanks!

userRoutes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { protectRoute } = require("../middleware/authMiddleware");
const {
  registerUser,
  loginUser,
  getUserProfile,
} = require("../controllers/userController");

router.post("/register", registerUser);
router.post("/login", loginUser);
router.get("/profile", protectRoute, getUserProfile);
module.exports = router;
```

authMiddleware.js

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");

const protectRoute = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")
  ) {
    try {
      token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, `{ process.env.JWT_SECRET}`);
      console.log(decoded);
      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select("-password");

      next();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return res.status(401).json({ error: "Not authorised. " });
    }
  }

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: "Not authorised. " });
  }
  next();
});

module.exports = { protectRoute };
```

userController.js

```
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const generateToken = (id) => {
  return jwt.sign({ id }, `{ process.env.JWT_SECRET}`, { expiresIn: "30d" });
};

const registerUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  const newUser = new User({ name, email, password });

  try {
    await newUser.save();
    res.send(newUser);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: error });
  }
};

const loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (user && (await user.matchPassword(password))) {
    res.json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    });
  } else {
    res.status(404).json({
      message: "Invalid email or password",
    });
  }
};
const getUserProfile = async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
  if (user) {
    return res.json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(404).send("User not found");
  }
};

module.exports = { getUserProfile, loginUser, registerUser };
```

server.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const pizzaRoutes = require("./routes/pizzaRoutes");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");
app.use(express.json());
connectDB();
app.use("/api/pizzas", pizzaRoutes);
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this issue occurs when you have returned the response and again you are trying to send the response.
Try one thing in `userController.js`, use common response method every where in try as well as catch block.
`return res.status(200).json({<json resp>})` in case of success.
`return res.status(<appropriate error code>).json({<send error in json format to>})` in case of error.